# Rails - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: subquery has too many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails 5 app, I'm receiving this error from a query, but I don't know how to fix it.

`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery has too many columns`

My controller:

```
def index
  @canvases = current_user.get_voted Canvas
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User").or(PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id)).or(PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where("key = ? AND recipient_id in (?)", "canvas_product.create", @canvases)).paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 30
end
```

The error is somewhere in this query:

```
(PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where("key = ? AND recipient_id in (?)", "canvas_product.create", @canvases))
```

Comment: At a guess... `@canvases` is a set of actual canvases, and maybe Rails isn't interpreting these as ids properly... try changing that to: `where("key = ? AND recipient_id in (?)", "canvas_product.create", @canvases.map(&:id))` - if that works, then you know that's what it was.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Is there any adjustment that I should do to limit @canvases to just be id's before the query (to be more efficient)?  Thank you!

Comment: I'll create an answer and add that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `@canvases` is a set of actual canvases, and maybe Rails isn't interpreting these as ids properly...

You can convert that to just ids like this:

```
where("key = ? AND recipient_id in (?)", "canvas_product.create", @canvases.map(&:id))
```

Alternatively you can use `pluck` on the association to pluck out just the ids you need eg:

```
@canvas_ids = current_user.get_voted(Canvas).pluck(:id)
```

(though this depends on how `get_voted` is written)

Comment: Better would be something like `where(:recipient_id => @canvases.select(:id))` if `@canvases` is a relation. That would get AR to use a subquery and leave the work inside the database.